# Is there a way to `dlopen` only specified (absolute) path on iOS?

Tags: ios, security, dlopen

When I checked the man-page for `dlopen` on iOS it says:

> When path contains a slash (i.e. a full path or a partial path) dlopen()
>        searches the following the following until it finds a compatible Mach-O
>        file: $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (with leaf name from path ), current working
>        directory (for partial paths), $DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH (with leaf
>        name from path ).

but according to POSIX (Open Group):

> The file argument is used to construct a pathname to the object file. If file contains a slash character, the file argument is used as the pathname for the file. Otherwise, file is used in an implementation-defined manner to yield a pathname.

So if you follow POSIX you could use `dlopen("/path/to/lib", 0)` to open precisely that file, but according to the iOS documentation it would search for a Mach-O file named `lib` in `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, current directory and finally `$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`.

If I really want to open just `/path/to/lib` under iOS and not any (possibly malign) `lib` found in the search path, what could I do?

(If I understand it correctly POSIX allows you to use a relative path too. Would that imply that it's a path relative to the current working directory then?)

Comment: if you are controlling the library, you could set have a function that only you set.. and and exit if you can't link it

Comment: and if you dont, then you could just check the version..

Comment: I think the idea of searching `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for security so you cannot open and run any library you liked at runtime.  I am not sure what part of POSIX you are quoting (I guess the manpage to `dlopen()`?) but those systems (including OSX) are more relaxed about loading dynamic libraries.  Whenever a relative file is used it's generally always relative to the current working directory, yes, as that is used as the base for such file ops.

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm not sure I agree about that. The POSIX standard says `dlopen` should open a specific library in this case, while iOS man page says it will open a "random" library based on what happens to be in `DYLIB_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` and which the current working directory happens to be. To me it does not sound more secure or less relaxed, it sounds rather the opposite. Btw the part of POSIX I'm quoting is the description of `dlopen` at Open Group.

Comment: @GradyPlayer But if that fails I don't get to open the library I would want to open...

Comment: if it fails to open any library then it certainly didn't open the wrong one

Comment: @GradyPlayer Yes, but if `/some/random` is in `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, then opening `/path/to/lib` will give me `/some/random/lib` - what do I do when/if I realize that it's not the droid I was looking for?